# display and rename android device connected to your portable hotspot programmatically

Tags: android, android-wifi

```
private void scan() {
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients = wifiApManager.getClientList(false);
device1.append("Clients: \n");
    for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients) {
        device1.append("####################\n");
        device1.append("IpAddr: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddr() + "\n");
        device1.append("Device: " + clientScanResult.getDevice() + "\n");
        device1.append("HWAddr: " + clientScanResult.getHWAddr() + "\n");
        device1.append("isReachable: " + clientScanResult.isReachable() + "\n");
    }
}
```

I use this code but there is nothing in display.

Comment: `i use this code but there nothing in display` Because the code you posted is appending things, not printing things.

Comment: so what should i do? do you have any idea how can i do it?

Comment: i need this its part of our project